# `ioctl` to read and write GPIO: invalid argument

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio, ioctl, invalid-argument

I'm imitating the [gpio-hammer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.66/source/tools/gpio) example in Linux source code. I'm using Raspberry Pi 3B+ and want an LED to blink.

Here's what I do:

```c
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int fd, ret;
    struct gpiohandle_request req;
    struct gpiohandle_data data;

    char *gpio_dev_name = "/dev/gpiochip0";
    unsigned int gpio_line = 8;

    memset(&data.values, 0, sizeof(data.values));

    // open device
    fd = open(gpio_dev_name, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s, %s\n",
                gpio_dev_name, strerror(errno));
    }

    // request gpio output
    req.lineoffsets[0] = gpio_line;
    req.flags = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT | GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_ACTIVE_LOW;
    strcpy(req.consumer_label, "blink");
    req.lines = 1;
    memcpy(req.default_values, &data, sizeof(req.default_values));

    ret = ioctl(fd, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &req);
    if (ret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to issue %s (%d), %s\n",
                "GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL", ret, strerror(errno));
    }

    // blink
    while (1) {
        // read data
        ret = ioctl(fd, GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, &data);
        if (ret == -1) {
            ret = -errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to issue %s (%d), %s\n", 
                    "GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL", ret, strerror(errno));
            exit(ret);
        }

        // flip digits
        data.values[0] = !data.values[0];

        // set data
        ret = ioctl(fd, GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, &data);
        if (ret == -1) {
            ret = -errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to issue %s (%d), %s\n", 
                    "GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL", ret, strerror(errno));
            exit(ret);
        }

        // delay
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I can compile the gpio-hammer example on RPi and run it with `./gpio-hammer -n gpiochip0 -o 8`. Attached to gpiochip0 line8 is an LED and it blinks.

But my program does not work. It fails with

```
Failed to issue GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL (-22), Invalid argument
```

I looked into the implement of [gpiolib](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.66/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L424). The `ioctl` of gpio line handle returns `EINVAL (22)` if ioctl cmd is not `GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL` nor `GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL`. But that's not the case. What's going wrong?

Comment: First of all, where is the error check for `open()` call? Second, on which iteration do you get the issue? I recommend to limit amount of iterations and use for-loop to print count for debugging purposes.

Comment: Also, update the post with the output from `gpio-hammer`.

Answer (score 1):

In `linux/gpio.h`, the [description](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.66/source/include/uapi/linux/gpio.h#L84) of `struct gpiohandle_request` says:

```c
/*
 * ...
 * @fd: if successful this field will contain a valid anonymous file handle
 * after a GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL operation, zero or negative value
 * means error
 */
struct gpiohandle_request {
    __u32 lineoffsets[GPIOHANDLES_MAX];
    __u32 flags;
    __u8 default_values[GPIOHANDLES_MAX];
    char consumer_label[32];
    __u32 lines;
    int fd;
};
```

When use `GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL`, the file handle of **GPIO chip** device is passed through the first argument of `ioctl()`, and **another** file handle will be sent back in `gpiohandle_request::fd`, if the operation successes. This new `fd` should be used in `ioctl` of `GPIO_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL` or `GPIO_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL`.

So the code should be

```c
ret = ioctl(fd, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &req);
if (ret == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to issue %s (%d), %s\n",
            "GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL", ret, strerror(errno));
}
else {
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close GPIO char dev.\n");
    }
    fd = req.fd;
}
```